# Can I made a full-width block before the footer on a 2columns-left page?

Tags: local.xml, footer

I would like to put a full-width block just before my footer on my search results page (`<catalogsearch_result_index>`) using my local.xml file, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I have a block I made as a core/template type that is working on other pages. It is a carousel with products in it. When I add it to the search results page, it shows up on the right side, not taking up the full width because it is a 2columns-left page.

I could add the block inside the footer itself at the top (which I have also had trouble accomplishing), but this would not be ideal since the background color for the footer differs from the block.

So, do you know of any way I can accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit

```
{magento_root}/app/design/frontend/{custom_package}/{custom_theme}/template/page/2columns-left.phtml
```

And just after the left column you add

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('full_width') ?>
```

Then in your local.xml

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="root">
     <block type="core/template" name="full_width" as="full_width" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Where template="path/to/template.phtml" is the path to your template file. For instance if  you added the template to the same folder as the 2columns-left.phtml then the template value would be template="page/full_width_static_block.phtml"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used the exact code you gave me and made a file called `full_width_static_block.phtml` and put the word "test" in it. The div is showing up, but the word "test" is not there. Any ideas what I might have done wrong? Thank you.

Comment: By cms static block I meant the static blocks configured in the backend. Will update my answer to use the template file (.phtml)

Comment: I forgot to include the reference node to so that the block is added as a child of the root block in your local.xml

Comment: I see. Thanks so much. I got it working with your second answer. Out of curiosity, why would someone use the static blocks configured in the backend? I found editing in the backend very annoying, so I made core/template type phtml files and call them in. Do the static blocks configured in the back end have some kind of advantage?

Comment: No advantage other that it's being able to edit in the admin pannel. Someone who isn't a programer or doesn't know Magento can update these without to much trouble or breaking things.

Comment: Thanks again. And if I wanted to have the same block on multiple pages (search result page, category page, & product page), I would just repeat the process, right? (with different handles obviously).

Comment: Yes but that depends on what template these pages use. For instance a product page can use 1column.phtml. Therefore you would need to either edit the 1column.phtml to include your new block or update your change the reference in your layout xml from root to content (Because it can span the whole width).

Comment: Ok. This is what I was wondering. I get the first part, editing the 1column.phtml to include the new block, but second part confuses me. Since it can span the whole width, wouldn't it be fine in a 1column layout? The difference between the root and content is unclear to me. I thought that content is like the body of the page.

Comment: I just meant because its a 1 column layout (spans the whole width) you can add your block as a child of the content block and then there would be no need to edit the 1column.phtml file. This is because all children's toHtml method of the content block is called automatically.

Comment: I see. Thank you. That makes sense. I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Are you able to mark answer as correct ?

Comment: The green check, right? Sorry about that. I tried to upvote it right after we started but I couldn't.